# Using py-sudoku library, how can i add the numbers in the board to the loop of entry boxes i created inside a frame with tkinter?

Tags: python, sudoku

I am creating a sudoku GUI and i dont know how to insert numbers from the given board (with empty spaces based on the difficulty level of the puzzle) and put them into the 9x9 table of entry boxes i created with a loop. I am putting the numbers inside as a row and not as a box of 3x3 for nine times.

Here the code starting from the frame and entry boxes inside it:

#THE FRAME

```
frame_blue = tk.Frame(new, width= 300, highlightbackground="darkblue", highlightthickness=5)
frame_blue.grid(padx=45, pady=105, ipadx=63, ipady=154)
frame_blue.grid_propagate(False)  # tell the frame to keep the size
```

#THE ENTRY BOXES inside the frame
def rows_columns():

```
    for row in range(0,9):
        for column in range(0,9):
            rows = tk.Entry(frame_blue,width=7, justify="center")
            rows.grid(row= row, column=column, ipady=6.6)
            #rows.config(state="disabled") #doesnt make the entry function as an input



rows_columns()
```